# Error: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I've been facing this error for a few days now and i don't know what the problem might be. Here's my logcat.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.sonnie.mytwende, PID: 5848
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database 
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:209)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:808)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:793)  
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:696)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:671)
at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:264)
at com.example.sonnie.mytwende.Database.addToBookings(Database.java:52)
at com.example.sonnie.mytwende.CarDetailsFragment$1.onClick(CarDetailsFragment.java:94)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

I've imported my SQLite DB in the assets/databases folder but I'm also getting this error on my database, i don't know if it might be the problem.

```
File was loaded in the wrong encoding:'UTF-8'
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission  android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
```

I'm supposed to click on the FAB then it adds the car into as an order in the db.

**CarDetails.java**

```
    btnBook=(FloatingActionButton) v.findViewById(R.id.btnBook);
    btnBook.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new Database(getContext()).addToBookings(new Order(
                    carid,
                    currentCar.getName(),
                  currentCar.getPricePerDay()
            ));

            StyleableToast st31= new StyleableToast(getActivity(),"Added to your bookings",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            st31.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#71DA98"));
            st31.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            st31.setIcon(R.drawable.success);
        }
    });
```

**CartFragment.java**

```
public class CartFragment extends Fragment {
TextView totalprice;
FButton btnPlaceOrder;
RecyclerView listBookings;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
FirebaseDatabase database;
DatabaseReference request;

List<Order> cart=new ArrayList<>();
CartAdapter adapter;

public CartFragment() {

}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cart, container, false);
    database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    request=database.getReference("Requests");

    listBookings=(RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.listBookings);
    listBookings.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    listBookings.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    totalprice=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.totalprice);
    btnPlaceOrder=(FButton) v.findViewById(R.id.btnPlaceOrder);

    List<Order> cart=new ArrayList<>();

    loadListCars();
    return v;
}

private void loadListCars() {
    cart=new Database(getContext()).getBoookings();
    adapter=new CartAdapter(cart,getContext());
    listBookings.setAdapter(adapter);

    int total=0;
    for(Order order:cart)
        total+=(Integer.parseInt(order.getCar_STPrice()))*(Integer.parseInt(order.getDays()));
    Locale locale=new Locale("en", "Ksh");
    NumberFormat fmat=NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);

    totalprice.setText(fmat.format(total));
}

}
```

**CartAdapter.java**

```
class CartViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
public TextView cart_item_name,cart_item_price;
public ImageView cart_item_count;

private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

public void setCart_item_name(TextView cart_item_name) {
    this.cart_item_name = cart_item_name;
}

public CartViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    cart_item_name=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cart_item_name);
    cart_item_price=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cart_item_price);
    cart_item_count=(ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cart_item_count);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

}
}

public class CartAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CartViewHolder>{

private List<Order> listData=new ArrayList<>();
private Context context;

public CartAdapter(List<Order> listData, Context context) {
    this.listData = listData;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public CartViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View itemView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.cart_layout,parent,false);
    return new CartViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CartViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Locale locale=new Locale("en", "Ksh");
    NumberFormat fmat=NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);
    int price=(Integer.parseInt(listData.get(position).getCar_STPrice()));
    holder.cart_item_price.setText(fmat.format(price));
    holder.cart_item_name.setText(listData.get(position).getCar_Name());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listData.size();
}
}
```

Comment: Which OS you are seeing this issue? It might be read/write pemission denied by user runtime in new os

Comment: phone android os version? What are pemissions defined in Manifest file? It looks like case of runtime permission error

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: I've added the code including the manifest permissions

Comment: Can anyone help me with this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47449608/unable-to-load-sqlite-database-on-first-run

Comment: The error occurred when the **`addToBookings`** method was called after the onClick, as  per `at com.example.sonnie.mytwende.Database.addToBookings(Database.java:52). 
at com.example.sonnie.mytwende.CarDetailsFragment$1.onClick(CarDetailsFragment.java:94)`. So you need to edit your question and add the **Database** class code.