# Android Architecture Components: using ViewModel for RecyclerView items

Tags: android, mvvm, android-recyclerview, android-architecture-components

I'm experimenting with the Architecture Components, and I want to build a ViewModel for each item of a RecyclerView. I'm not sure if that is formally correct or I should stick with the "old way".

I have this adapter:

```java
public class PostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter.PostViewHolder> {

    private List<Post> list;
    public static class PostViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        final ItemPostBinding binding;

        public PostViewHolder(ItemPostBinding binding){
            super(binding.getRoot());
            this.binding = binding;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public PostViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        ItemPostBinding binding = DataBindingUtil
                .inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), R.layout.item_post,
                        parent, false);


        return new PostViewHolder(binding, parent.getContext());
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PostViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.binding.setPost(list.get(position));
        holder.binding.executePendingBindings();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list == null ? 0 : list.size();
    }

    public void setList(List<Post> list){
        this.list = list;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

which works fine but it's very basic. how do I update it so each item has it's own ViewModel associated? is that even possible?

EDIT: playing with it, I've tried to put in ViewModels the following way:

```java
public class PostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter.PostViewHolder> {

    private List<Post> list;
    public static class PostViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        final ItemPostBinding binding;
        private final Context context;
        private GalleryItemViewModel viewModel;

        public PostViewHolder(ItemPostBinding binding, Context context){
            super(binding.getRoot());
            this.binding = binding;
            this.context = context;
        }

        public Context getContext(){
            return context;
        }

        public void setViewModel(GalleryItemViewModel viewModel){
            this.viewModel = viewModel;
            binding.setViewModel(viewModel);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public PostViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        ItemPostBinding binding = DataBindingUtil
                .inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), R.layout.item_post,
                        parent, false);


        return new PostViewHolder(binding, parent.getContext());
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PostViewHolder holder, int position) {
        GalleryItemViewModel vm = ViewModelProviders.of((FragmentActivity) holder.getContext()).get(GalleryItemViewModel.class);
        vm.setPost(list.get(position));
        holder.setViewModel(vm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list == null ? 0 : list.size();
    }

    public void setList(List<Post> list){
        this.list = list;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

it works but is that the correct way to do it?

Comment: hello Jacopo , you can use adapter in different way..

Comment: can you give me an example or a link to follow?

Comment: you can check the answer from bellow link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47432835/displaying-data-in-a-recyclerview/47433409#47433409

Comment: if you feel till problem then ask me...

Comment: I don't see how this can help me, the given example does not use either databinding or viewmodels

Comment: `ViewModelProviders.of((FragmentActivity) holder.getContext()).get(GalleryItemViewModel.class)`
Wouldn't this return same `GalleryItemViewModel` object on subsequent calls? I guess you should use the overloaded method `get(@NonNull String key, @NonNull Class<T> modelClass)` of `ViewModelProvider` and passing unique key to get unique viewModel per `onBindViewHolder` call.

Comment: The ViewModel is created only once for all ViewHolders because the `context` passed comes from the parent. That's why it is working wrong, isn't it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all correct implementation of ViewModel should be by extending `android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel`. The examples that extending `BaseObservable` which makes ViewModel class a data class but it should be presentation class since it's replacing the presenter of MVP pattern.

Another thing is `ViewModelProviders.of(context).get(Class.class)` returns the same ViewModel for every call and it lets you to share same data between views.

Also, ViewModel class should not, or contain minimum classes from Android environment and should not keep any references to view classes since it may outlive the views.

In your second example you probably getting same ViewModel from Activity/Fragment using

```
public void setViewModel(GalleryItemViewModel viewModel){
            this.viewModel = viewModel;
            binding.setViewModel(viewModel);
}
```

Can you share layout file and how you implement this with ViewModel class?

Link for sample in accepted answer is not a correct example for MVVM and data binding.

ViewModel class from the link set as you second example:

```
public class CommentHeaderViewModel extends BaseObservable {

    private Context context;
    private Post post;

    public CommentHeaderViewModel(Context context, Post post) {
        this.context = context;
        this.post = post;
    }

    public String getCommentText() {
        return Html.fromHtml(post.text.trim()).toString();
    }

    public String getCommentAuthor() {
        return context.getResources().getString(R.string.text_comment_author, post.by);
    }

    public String getCommentDate() {
        return new PrettyTime().format(new Date(post.time * 1000));
    }

}
```

This is a data class, not an ViewModel class as [architecture components page](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) states, it also imports view classes which is bad for unit testing.

It's data binding + RecyclerView tutorial, correct naming should not be ..ViewModel for this class. [Check out this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDatabinding/article.html#using-data-binding-in-android-applications) for data class and binding it with RecyclerView.

Comment: Will take a look! Thanks for now

Comment: ViewModel class shouldn't have a context reference.

Comment: I wrote that it shouldn't, please read carefully. _Also, ViewModel class should not, or contain minimum classes from Android environment and should not keep any references to view classes since it may outlive the views._ That snippet show how ViewModel is used before and should not be used now, it's data class, not currently used architectural class for ViewModel.

Answer (score 10):

Funny, but answer - This is correct way, should be accepted :)
You can make some code clean-up and remove `GalleryItemViewModel` from `PostViewHolder`, because you are creating hard reference and not using it.
Then dirrectly in `onBindViewHolder()` use it like `holder.binding.setViewModel(vm);`

This is a [link](https://github.com/hitherejoe/MVVM_Hacker_News/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/hitherejoe/mvvm_hackernews/view/adapter/CommentAdapter.java) with MVVM code example that can help you.

Answer (score 4):

**Make sure you assign an unique identifier when getting the ViewModel, because under the hood the ViewModelProviders will give you the same instance otherwise**

*get(**some unique id**, GalleryItemViewModel.class);*

So please try adding an id there, like below :

```
 GalleryItemViewModel vm = ViewModelProviders.of((FragmentActivity) holder.getContext()).get(**some unique id**, GalleryItemViewModel.class);
    vm.setPost(list.get(position));
    holder.setViewModel(vm);
```

Comment: Good point on passing in unique `key`, however it's not needed in this case because he calls the `vm::setPost` on every binding, which presumably re-assigns all fields. Although I'm not sure if the way he's doing it would cause any performance issue.